# How to use PHP with a non-PHP enabled webhost?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I have a website that is being hosted on WebFlow. It's a front-end editor, with the ability to write Javascript.

I have some PHP files of API calls that need to be executed for certain functions to work. WebFlow is not PHP enabled. I was told I can host them on Amazon.

What are the basic steps to host my files on Amazon, and make API requests from WebFlow?

Comment: When you say WebFlow is a front-end editor, do you have the ability to write Javascript  - or is the interface strictly WYSIWYG?

Comment: You can write javascript, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your question is quite broad, so I'll cover the overview of the steps you could take:**

You can host your PHP files on any PHP enabled web-service, it doesn't *have* to be Amazon Web Services (AWS).

Having said this, AWS does offer you greater control over your development stack, when compared with a run-of-the-mill web host; which may be a benefit/requirement to you.

Most online tutorials (including Amazon's own documentation) will tell you to set up a PHP enabled Amazon EC2 container, and guide you through the basics of security and setting up the virtual network for the container to run on, and ultimately allow you to send requests to it over the internet.

This, from experience, can be a very frustrating task for first-time users of AWS. So, instead - I'd recommend you looked at a simpler option, also provided by Amazon: [Amazon Lightsail](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/).

In a nutshell (from the Lightsail FAQ page):

> Amazon Lightsail is the easiest way to get started with AWS for developers, small businesses, students, and other users who need a simple virtual private server (VPS) solution. Lightsail provides developers compute, storage, and networking capacity and capabilities to deploy and manage websites and web applications in the cloud. Lightsail includes everything you need to launch your project quickly – a virtual machine, SSD-based storage, data transfer, DNS management, and a static IP – for a low, predictable monthly price.

**Steps to take:**

1. Set up an account with Amazon Web Services, and sign up for a Lightsail plan. Amazon's own documentation will tell you what to do, in very easy to understand terms.
2. Find an appropriate image to base your Lightsail instance from - a basic LAMP stack should suffice.
3. Upload your files to the Lightsail instance, and ensure they are accessible from a publicly accessible directory (i.e /var/www - read the documentation in AWS)
4. Once you have a Lightsail instance up and running - you can write Javascript (within WebFlow) to send an AJAX request to your PHP files, and parse the response that comes back.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed to know.